Vectorisation of loop accessing preceding values on a row by row basis
I need to roll through a dataframe and update the estimate in column 2 based on the previous value in column 1 and column 2. I am looking for ideas on how to vectorise this approach/speed it up as it is currently quite costly in the loop format below. The first row is set to 0 as there is no preceding value.
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if idx == 0:
        df.loc[idx, 'column2'] = 0
    else:
        df.loc[idx, 'column2'] = (df.loc[idx - 1, 'column1'] + df.loc[idx - 1, 'column2']) * DECAY

# Expected output -

   column1  column2
0        1      0.0
1        2      0.9
2        3      2.61
3        4      5.049
4        5     8.1441


I have added this @ScottBoston. Not the additional edits with regards to DECAY.

You can use numpy to get the dot product of a matrix that takes DECAY into account:
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

DECAY = 0.9

n = len(df)
dm = np.tril(np.power(DECAY, np.subtract.outer(np.arange(n), np.arange(n))), -1)
df["column2"] = dm.dot(df["column1"])

   column1  column2
0        1   0.0000
1        2   0.9000
2        3   2.6100
3        4   5.0490
4        5   8.1441


Intermediate steps for clarity:
Create a matrix m with the subtraction of all pairs from an array with range [0, n]:
m = np.subtract.outer(np.arange(n), np.arange(n))

[[ 0 -1 -2 -3 -4]
 [ 1  0 -1 -2 -3]
 [ 2  1  0 -1 -2]
 [ 3  2  1  0 -1]
 [ 4  3  2  1  0]]

Elevate DECAY to the power of each element in m:
p = np.power(DECAY, m)

[[1.         1.11111111 1.2345679  1.37174211 1.5241579 ]
 [0.9        1.         1.11111111 1.2345679  1.37174211]
 [0.81       0.9        1.         1.11111111 1.2345679 ]
 [0.729      0.81       0.9        1.         1.11111111]
 [0.6561     0.729      0.81       0.9        1.        ]]

Keep the lower triangle of the matrix:
dm = np.tril(p, -1)

[[0.     0.     0.     0.     0.    ]
 [0.9    0.     0.     0.     0.    ]
 [0.81   0.9    0.     0.     0.    ]
 [0.729  0.81   0.9    0.     0.    ]
 [0.6561 0.729  0.81   0.9    0.    ]]


Alternative approach using less memory, taking on average 2.7 seconds for the example dataframe on my machine:
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": np.arange(1, 60001)})

DECAY = 0.9

n = len(df)
c = np.zeros(n)
factors = np.power(DECAY, np.arange(n))

for i in range(1, n):
    c[i] = np.dot(factors[1 : i + 1][::-1], df["column1"][:i])

df["column2"] = c

       column1      column2
0            1       0.0000
1            2       0.9000
2            3       2.6100
3            4       5.0490
4            5       8.1441
...        ...          ...
59995    59996  539874.0000
59996    59997  539883.0000
59997    59998  539892.0000
59998    59999  539901.0000
59999    60000  539910.0000

[60000 rows x 2 columns]


Thanks. If you look carefully,  the result in column 2 is a result of both data in column 1 and column 2, not just column 1 as per your example.

I read @e-motta 's answer a few times before getting it. As per your example, the first entry in column 2 is zero. The second is the first entry in column 1 (plus zero). The third is the second entry in col 2 (=first entry in col 1) plus the second entry in col 1, i.e. the sum of the first two entries in column 1. If we keep going, the nth entry in column 2 is the (n-1)th entry in col 1 plus the (n-1)th entry in col 2, which is in turn the cumulative sum of the first (n-2) terms in col 1.

@Tim I understand, but do notice that if you apply your logic, the value from column2 is the sum of all previous values from column1, and this generalizes to a cumulative sum. You can verify that by using your code on the same dataset. Of course, this only works if you want to sum the values; if you need to perform other operations, you will need to adapt this, or even use a different approach, but that's not specified in your question (you can edit and clarify it, if that's the case).

@e-motta you are right. I was trying to simplify the problem to share on SO, but actually omitted an important part. I want to modify each row by DECAY, before the next row is calculated - see edit. PaulWilson thank you for your explanation.

@Tim That's a bit trickier, but you can do it using numpy. See my updated answer.

@e-motta it does work correctly, and I've marked it correct. However, the dataframe size is 66k rows so the memory required to create an array 66k x 66k limits its effectiveness to smaller df sizes. I appreciate this wasn't part of the intial scope of the question, but if you have any ways around this, it would be appreciated.

@Tim I updated my answer with an alternative approach. It should be faster than pure iteration, but not by much (about 2x on my machine for the example dataframe). I can't think of anything better than that, sorry.

You can use np.ufunc.accumulate for this.  Provided you create a custom ufunc for your operator.  The only catch is, you also need to prepend a zero to your input data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
DECAY = 0.9

def y_next(y, u):
    return DECAY * (y + u)

# Make custom ufunc
y_next_ufunc = np.frompyfunc(y_next, nin=2, nout=1)

# Prepend inputs with 0
u = np.concatenate([[0.0], df['column1']])

y = y_next_ufunc.accumulate(u[:-1])
df['column2'] = y

print(df)

output:
   column1 column2
0        1     0.0
1        2     0.9
2        3    2.61
3        4   5.049
4        5  8.1441


If speed is important you should time it.  I'm not sure whether custom ufuncs are vectorized.

You can use np.tril, because you want each row to represent the sum of all previous values up to that point, which aligns with the nature of a lower triangular matrix.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
decay = 10 

decayfactors = decay ** np.arange(len(df))
print(decayfactors)#[   1   10  100 1000]

l = len(df)
tril_matrix = np.tril(np.ones((l,l))) * decayfactors[:,None]
print(tril_matrix)
'''

[[   1.    0.    0.    0.]
 [  10.   10.    0.    0.]
 [ 100.  100.  100.    0.]
 [1000. 1000. 1000. 1000.]]
'''
col2 = np.dot(tril_matrix,df['column1'].values)

df['column2'] = col2
print(df)
'''
   column1  column2
0        1      1.0
1        2     30.0
2        3    600.0
3        4  10000.0
'''

